# regular expressions: ignoring order a character in a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Is there a way I can use regular expressions to find characters in different orders?
For example: 
lets say I have this string:

```
string="I want to find JKD:Jdj:SL? and YK:kd?"
```

Is there a regular expression I can use to find `YK:kd?` and `JKD:Jdj:SL?` 
Right now I only know how to find specifically `YK:kd?` by doing something like

```
 re.findall('\w+\:\w+\?',string)
```

but I don't know how to find expressions that just contain : in them in a general sense, excluding the order and how many there are.

Answer (score 2):

Add an optional (at least one) number of leading `XXX:` strings:

```
re.findall(r'((?:\w+:)+\w+\?)', string)
```

---

Code test result:

```
>>> re.findall(r'((?:\w+:)+\w+\?)', "I want to find JKD:Jdj:SL? and YK:kd?")
```

Output:

```
['JKD:Jdj:SL?', 'YK:kd?']
```

Comment: for some reasons this doesn't work with python3 . do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Bob I added `r` before the string literal so the string will be compiled to a regex. Try it now.

Comment: I tested it [online](https://www.python.org/shell/) and the (newly edited) code works - see test output

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
re.findall(r'\w+(?::\w+)+\?',string)
```

Details

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?::\w+)+` - one or more occurrences of a colon followed by one or more word chars (note the use of `(?:...)` non-capturing group that allows `re.findall` return just whole matches)
- `\?` - a question mark.

Comment: @Bob Use [`\w+(?::\w+)+\?`](https://regex101.com/r/lKlyW6/1). What are your expected results? See https://ideone.com/eE0LXo, my solution returns `['JKD:Jdj:SL?', 'YK:kd?', 'JKD:askdlfj:Jdj:SL?']`. Do you expect `['YK:kd?']` only? Then use [`rx = r"(?<!:)\b\w+:\w+\?"`](https://ideone.com/yzqcNY) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lKlyW6/2).

Comment: @Bob I finished writing the comment.

Comment: @Bob Note I was away from PC, and posted the answer from a mobile when I saw none of the answers really solved the issue at all, only some 4 hours later the 2 answers became almost identical, mine still being more efficient (132 steps vs 199 Bohemian's).